# MVC and multiple google checkout merchant ids

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, credit-card, google-checkout, merchant-account

This will be my first time to handle credit card transactions and merchant ids. I have a site that offers services to both event organizers and its users. If a user would want to buy tickets for an event, I want the money to go to the organizers directly. I was thinking I have to handle this with an organizer having their own merchant ids and just store them. My question is though, do I have to ask for their merchant key as well?

As a follow up question, is this a better way to handle transactions instead of having just one merchant id (the website) and funnel the money through it and distribute to the organizers from the users, at the same time charging them for some extra fee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the money to go to the organizers directly

Then you should think of your implementation as a "service provdier only" that has Google Checkout "integrated" into your service. Your relationship is defined as such - while your customers - event organizers and *their* customers have their own relationship(s) with Google Checkout

This way you are **not** *party* to the transaction that occurs between them and Google Checkout.

Additionally, Google Checkout only pays out *directly* to the merchant (they don't have any *other* type of "disbursement" that I know of).

> is this a better way to handle transactions instead of having just one merchant id (the website) and funnel the money through it and distribute to the organizers from the users, at the same time charging them for some extra fee

I think you already realize the pitfalls just by asking it - you realize that its not **just** a technical matter - you have your own liability to think about when you are party to the transaction(s).

- What would you do on a chargeback? It's your account that is "hit" by that...
- What would you do on a refund?
- What would you do when there is a dispute between event organizer and *their* customer?

In these sample cases, **you** will have to deal with all of them - your "users" are *"irrelevant"* to Google Checkout (they don't "exist" in Google's eyes).

Also, I'm no lawyer btw, but Google doesn't allow any "fee" that is somehow *added to the transaction for use of Google Checkout*,  per their TOS.

Comment: Oh man, thank you for the detailed reply, ive been lost with this functionality for a month now. Since i'm only starting this by myself and have limited funds,handling these situations(me handling the money) may not be the best way to go. But eventually if the organizers would need me do the processing for them, google checkout may not be the way to go for me (thoughts?) I'm basing this off of eventbrite's model in charging the users the processing fee, do you think they're adding some processing on top of that? seems hat they're using a different cc processing service?

Comment: I wouldn't know who EventBrite uses for processing payments - either way, even if you did process cards directly, via a credit card processor service, the same questions apply (e.g. chargeback hits you). IMHO, the safest option is for you to charge for usage of your service inclusive of integrations with whomever you choose to process payments - **not the payment processing itself** (don't be party to the transaction itself).

Comment: so google and checkout then right? and just have them get their merchant id themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If your merchant account is used for sales then you're reselling the event tickets.

As a reseller, you can provide a very clean experience to your customers. But you'd be paying the event organizers later on (not in the same transaction). A good reason to pay the event organizers later is that you can hold all or part of their money in escrow to cover yourself in the case of a chargeback.

If you want the customer's money to go **directly** to the event organizers, I think there are some methods:

1. The customers sell via paypal, google checkout, authorize.net, etc. You direct the customer to the (event organizers) payment page and then back to your site. I think this is what EventBrite is doing. You'd need to collect your fee from the event organizer separately. (You could simultaneously charge a credit card owned by the event organizer.)
2. You use Amazon Payments which explicitly includes a 3rd party feature. -- It enables you (the 3rd party) to control a transaction that occurs between two other parties (the event organizer and the end customer)

Good luck!

Comment: thanks Larry! i didn't know amazon payments has that functionality!!
and thanks for the taking the time to answer this!